# Xcode iOS Photo Gallery Application

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, gallery, photo

I am relatively new to Xcode and am trying to create a simple application.

I want to create a landing screen which looks very similar to that of the "Photos" app landing screen. It has all of the images laid out in thumbnails, when you click one, it grows to fullscreen. You can also scroll through the images, save to camera roll and so on.

Can anyone offer me any help or advice?

Answer (score 8):

Nimbus is very good as well and more lightweight than three20.  http://nimbuskit.info/

I think their sample projects have an example that does almost just that.

https://github.com/jverkoey/nimbus/tree/master/examples/photos/NetworkPhotoAlbums

Answer (score 2):

[Three20](http://three20.info/) is the most popular.

A valid alternative is  [PhotoViewer](https://github.com/enormego/PhotoViewer) , and you can read more about how the code works [here](http://developers.enormego.com/).

[Here](http://codecanyon.net/item/photogallery-ios-xcode-project/153822) is another cool Photo Gallery, but is paid.

Comment: If you're just experimenting it might be worth looking into the new things that come with iOS 6 that might make this easier. Which nobody can tell you about here because it's all under NDA, but if you go over to the Apple Developer Forums you can find out more.